# Is it correct to say "I feel vomit/puke/throw-up when I smell pork fat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

"**Feel**" is a linking verb and we often use adjectives after liking verbs.

We normally use adjectives after "**feel**"

For example, *Do you still feel hungry?* ([source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/feel))

But we can use a noun after "**feel**", too.

For example, *Stop exercising if you feel any pain.* ([source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/feel))

Now, "**vomit**", "**throw-up**" and "**puke**" are nouns

Can we say "**I feel vomit/puke/throw-up when I smell pork fat**"?

But, "**vomit**", "**throw up**" and "**puke**" are also verbs, and we can convert them into adjectives by adding "**ing**" to become "**vomiting**", "**throwing-up**" and "**puking**"

Can we say "**I feel vomiting/puking/throwing-up when I smell pork fat**"?

Some suggest to put "**like**" after  "**feel**", "**I feel like vomiting/puking/throwing-up when I smell pork fat**", but I am not so sure.

Comment: The idiomatic standard is ***I feel sick***. For your continuous participle alternatives, it would have to be something along the lines of *I feel **like** vomiting/puking/throwing-up*. Or *The smell of pork fat **makes me** [want to] vomit / puke / throw up*.

Comment: You should make that an answer @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica

Answer (score 3):

We can use a noun with feel only when it mean an emotion or mental state. So "feel pain" is possible.  With more concrete nouns, "feel something" means "touch it with your hands".  Therefore "feel vomit" gives the wrong meaning.

There are several adjectives that you can use: "sick", "nauseous", "nauseated" are three. (The latter ones are more formal)

You can use a verb (in its present participle/gerund form) with "feel like". Or you can say "... makes me want to..."

So "I feel sick when I smell pork fat" or "I feel like throwing up..." or "The smell of pork fat makes me want to puke".

Comment: Note that not all dictionaries (and speakers) have accepted the new use of “nauseous” for this.

Comment: I was going to mention that, the use of "nauseous" is widespread, but considered incorrect by some  I decided not to mention it to avoid introducing an unnecessary complexity. In traditional use, the disgusting thing is "nauseous" or "nauseating".  But the person is "nauseated".  There is no problem with nauseated.

Comment: What about "I feel a headache / stomachache"? Is it ok to say like that? Or "I feel like having a headache / stomachache"

Comment: I'd understand "I feel a headache", but its unusual (not natural).  "I have a headache" or "I feel a headache coming on" are correct.  "I feel like having a headache" means "I want a headache" (so  it is correct but the meaning is very strange)

Comment: If you are describing HOW you feel something, that is an adverb. If you are describing WHAT you feel, then it is a noun (direct object). These are true regardless of which meaning of feel you intend. If you are describing how you yourself feel, it can be an adjective. ("I feel nauseated" is basically the same as "I am nauseated")